# Properties of Hodge Duality

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers

So we know that [Hodge duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_dual) works this way

$$⋆(dx^{i_1} \wedge ... \wedge dx^{i_p})= \frac{1}{(n-p)!} \epsilon^{i_1..i_p}_{i_{p+1}..i_n} dx^{i_{p+1} } \wedge dx^{i_n}$$

where $p$ represents the $p$ in $p$-form and $n$ is the dimensional number.

My question is: How does hodge duality work on the imaginary number $i$ on one hand and on partial derivative like $\partial_x\alpha$ let us say on the other where $\alpha$ is a complex function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hodge star operation acts on differential forms. Numbers, real or complex, transform as 0-forms. The Hodge dual of a 0-form will result in something proportional to the volume form of the manifold. In detail, for a $d$-dimensional manifold,

$\star 1 = \text{vol}_d = \sqrt{|g|}dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^d$,

and the Hodge operation commutes with multiplication by complex numbers.

A partial derivative like $\partial_x \alpha$ is also a complex number (in general), so the above applies. However, given a scalar function such as $\alpha$, a 1-form can be obtained as

$d\alpha = (\partial_i \alpha) dx^i$.

Then the Hodge star acts on $d\alpha$ as it would on any 1-form.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have some questions on what you said.

Do you mean that $\star i = \text{vol}_d = i\sqrt{|g|}dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^d$, 
or just the same as the one you wrote, $\star 1 = \text{vol}_d = \sqrt{|g|}dx^1 \wedge ... \wedge dx^d$?

Second I can't see how the partial derivative is also a complex number? May you please elaborate on this one?

Third if it happens that $\star{(i\partial _x \alpha)}$ what will happen in this case?

Comment: So $\star c$, where $c$ is ANY complex number, is simply $c \star 1$, where $\star 1$ is defined above. The complex derivative is a number, either real or complex valued. Perhaps I should have emphasized this, but real vs. complex is a completely irrelevant issue for Hodge duality--the only thing that matters is the tensor structure of the object you are dualising. So $\partial_x \alpha$ is just some number, call it $c$, and everything I said before goes through.

Comment: By the way, there are many good references on Hodge duality. I learned from this book: http://www.amazon.com/Geometry-Topology-Physics-Edition-Graduate/dp/0750306068

Comment: Thanks! By the way concerning your determinant of g in the definition.. I have never seen this before in the definition of hodge duality. If you take  a look back at my definition in the question above you see the summation and the fraction on the righthand side.. Are they related in some sort of way? @Surgical Commander

Comment: Well the determinant is secretly present in your expression above, it's hidden in the epsilon tensor. In curved space there is a difference between the usual Levi-Civita symbol which is a tensor density, and the symbol which appears in your formula which is a tensor. Any book which discusses Hodge duality should also cover the differences between the two.

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 4):

If you are working on a complex manifold with a Hermitian metric, then the Hodge star operator should be taken *anti*linear: $\star(\alpha + i\beta) = \star\alpha - i\star\beta$. If you work on a real manifold without a complex structure by itself, and you extend the scalars to the complex numbers, it may be that there is no harm in taking it to be linear.